# How to handle emails from being found on Linked-In?

Tags: email, linkedin, unprofessional-behavior

Recently I have been received unsolicited advertisement emails in my "work email" inbox. I logged onto Linked-In an noticed I have connection requests from these people as well.

The email address I have associated with my Linked-In account is not my work email, but a personal account. However, I feel these advertisers have connected the dots and found (like I am sure many companies do) that my work email is `first initial - last name @ company name .com`.

How should I handle these people? I am planning on blocking them in my email program and obviously not adding them to my Linked-In network. Are there other steps I should take, like reporting them to Linked-In?

Comment: Is it a one off or are you bombarded by emails?

Comment: I wouldn't say "bombarded", maybe 1 or 2 from each user. It just started happening though. The email side is the easy solution... just send them to "junk".

Comment: If your concern is that you're going to get into trouble at work for misuse of email, that is extremely unlikely if you're not actually replying using company email/company time and engaging them in conversation.  Spam happens; it's just part of using email.  Into the junk folder, and move on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LinkedIn is not responsible for anything you receive in your work e-mail.  They're not chasing down spammers for you.  That's either your job, or your company's.  And *anyone* who knows your first name, last name, and where you work could send you the same kind of e-mail.  If you want to remove the risk that it's coming from LinkedIn members viewing your profile, remove your information.

If this were people snail-mailing you stuff because you published your street address and name in the white pages, how would you solve this???  Again, you'd remove your information.

If you are getting UCE (spam) in your work e-mail box, then you either (a) ignore it, and filter out the offenders or (b) report each occurrence with the Federal Trade Commission [here](https://www.ftccomplaintassistant.gov/#crnt&panel1-1).  No one with anything better to do with their time is going to chase these people down for you because you received a handful of messages.  As for the FTC, they have a long, long, line of offenses ahead of yours, and they focus on situations where spammers are sending messages out by the thousands.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say you're getting far too worried about this. Just make a decision about whether you want to connect with the person - if you do, connect with them. If you don't, ignore the mail and move on. Job done, stop spending your (work) time on what is a molehill, not a mountain.